# MariaDB: How to consider local date format with STR_TO_DATE?

Tags: mysql, mariadb, str-to-date

I have a csv file which I want to load into a table. It has a column with the following date format:

```
'%d-%b-%y'
```

For example: `'01-Dez-18'`. If I load this file considering the format:

```
IF(@entry_dt = '',NULL,STR_TO_DATE(@entry_dt, '%d-%b-%y'))
```

I get a warning:

> Incorrect datetime value: '01-Dez-12' for function str_to_date

This is due to the format of the column which is `de_CH` but the local and global settings are `en_US`. That is the reason why `01-Jan-12` was loaded correctly. Changing the local setting

```
SET lc_time_names = 'de_CH';
```

does not work since:

> lc_time_names does not affect the STR_TO_DATE() or GET_FORMAT() function

(see [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/locale-support.html)).

Is there a way to load the date column considering German/Swiss notation?

Answer (score 1):

The Monthname is in German (Dez). If you change it to Dec it works.

if you want to get the german names you must install the **locale Plugin**

1) see if already installed:

```
show plugins;
```

2) install the Plugin

```
INSTALL SONAME 'locales';
```

3) set local or set it global in the my.ini

```
SET  lc_time_names = 'de_DE';
select STR_TO_DATE('01-Dec-18', '%d-%b-%y');
```

Comment: Ì did step 2) and 3) but it does not work. In the documentation it was mentioned that `lc_times_names` does not affect `STR_TO_DATE`. Maybe if I change globally? How can I change globally?